# How do you stop the latest version of iexplore.exe from immediately exiting when started with a URL argument?

Tags: internet-explorer, process, browser-automation

I am trying to open an IE window to allow a user to go through a web based OAUTH process.

We need to be able to detect if the user has closed the window, so we can tell them authorization was denied, and offer them an option to try again.

Additionally, if they complete the authorisation process (which we can detect in our main WPF app), we want to close the window, without user interaction (i.e. confirmation).

To do this, I am starting the process manually as follows:

```
        _authProcess = Process.Start($"{programFilePath}\\{_iExplorePath}", $"-noframemerging {AuthorizationUrl}");

        _authProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        _authProcess.Exited += AuthProcess_Exited;
```

I can then handle the event to detect the close, and if they complete the authorization, terminate the process to close the browser window automatically.

This sometimes works flawlessly for hours, with or without other IE windows open, however, other times it opens the URL in an un-trackable third process and terminates the _authProcess immediately (exit code 1).

I am using -noframemerging to tell it not to use an existing instance. I have also tried -nosessionmerging, and -nomerge, and -new, in various combinations.

Comment: This authorization process, does it require user interaction and if so what kind?

Comment: Yes, the remote system prompts them to log in and agree that the calling application can access their data.

Comment: In the end, I found that creating registry entries, as follows, enabled the WebBrowser control to be used, as you can switch it to operate as a modern web browser (it originally couldn't be used as it didn't support JQuery 2+, upon which the OAuth process was dependant): [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"appName.exe"=dword:00002af9